# How to efficiently query from Firebase Realtime Database using query or specific path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have infrequently property modification("price") on Firebase Realtime Database which is structure like this:

```
../currencies/<currency>/value/
      "price":343
```

every player that log in will listen to only one and specific currency. our client will pick the right currency path based on the player preferences.

so if player is set to currency USD the firebase client will listen to this path

```
../currencies/USD/value/
      "price":343
```

Those currencies prices are changed infrequently
due to this structure our server side need to modify and denormalized the data to all currencies when it changes (we can have ten's of currencies)
because of that we add to the  leaf even more properties which are **identical** at all currencies

which I find redudent like:

```
../currencies/USD/value/
          "price":343
          "currency-source":"fx" . //this property will be copied to all
```

currencies vals because the client listen to only one path and it needs this data aswell

instead if manitain this on path's perhaps we can use some query where each client will be able to pick it's currency based on property name?

something like that:

```
../currencies/value/
          "USD_price":343
          "EUR_price":343
      ...
```

thoughts about design? and if sounds better how can be achieved with Firebase Realtime Database query?

Comment: That seems indeed totally feasible. Do you encouter any difficulty listening to the `../currencies/value/<currency>_price` node compare to the `../currencies/<currency>/value` one? "how can be achieved with Firebase database query" -> Which SDK(s) are you using (JS, Android, iOS)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec we dont have difficulty i just think it complexing our firebase tree model without real value. we using JS SDK

Comment: "it complexifies our firebase tree model without real value" -> which approach complexify it ? listening to the ../currencies/value/<currency>_price node or listening to  ../currencies/<currency>/value one? What are you actually asking? What is the best approach?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec ./currencies/<currency>/value one?  -> make things complex (as I detailed in my question) because we replicat all properties.  and i have no idea how to use the ./currencies/value/<currency>_price approach on the client side so he will take only the currency the player was opted to. will be happy if you could show me the way by answer this question

Comment: Which language are you using in your front-end? I.e. which Firebase Client SDK are you using?

Comment: I have worked out an answer for the JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which language (which Client SDK) you use in your app, but here is a solution with the JavaScript SDK.

Let's imagine you have a Relatime Database structure as follows

```
  "parentnode" : {
    "currencies" : {
      "EUR" : {
        "value" : {
          "price" : 201
        }
      },
      "USD" : {
        "value" : {
          "price" : 343
        }
      },
      "value" : {
        "EUR_price" : 201,
        "USD_price" : 343,
        "currency-source" : "fx"
      }
    }
  }
```

Under a `parentnode` you have a `currencies` node **which corresponds to the examples in your question**.

In case you want to listen to `/currencies/<currency>/value`, you would do as follows:

```
  var db = firebase.database();

  var currency = 'EUR';

  var ref = db.ref().child('parentnode/currencies/' + currency);
  ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
  });
```

In case you want to listen to `/currencies/value/<currency>_price` and get the `price` and the `currency-source` values, you would do as follows:

```
  var db = firebase.database();

  var currency = 'EUR';

  var ref = db.ref().child('parentnode/currencies/value');
  ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var price = data[currency + '_price'];
    var source = data['currency-source'];
    console.log(price);
    console.log(source);
  });
```

---

As mentioned in your comment, the second approach implies that "we will download all the data leaf under `/currencies/value/`".

I can think of two other possible approaches. Choosing one over the other really depends on your functional requirements, i.e. what you do with these values in your front-end.

#### 1/ Set two listeners

The idea is to set one listener for `'parentnode/currencies/value/' + currency + '_price'` and one for `'parentnode/currencies/value/currency-source'`, as follows:

```
  var currency = 'EUR';

  var ref2 = db
    .ref()
    .child('parentnode/currencies/value/' + currency + '_price');
  ref2.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
  });

  var ref3 = db.ref().child('parentnode/currencies/value/currency-source');
  ref3.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
  });
```

#### 2/ Query the `currency-source` value within the listener

With this second approach, in the listener to `'parentnode/currencies/value/' + currency + '_price'`, we query the database with the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once) method to get the value of `currency-source`:

```
  var ref4 = db
    .ref()
    .child('parentnode/currencies/value/' + currency + '_price');
  ref4.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    db.ref()
      .child('parentnode/currencies/value/currency-source')
      .once('value')
      .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
        console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      });
  });
```

---

Note that if you do not need to set a listener, i.e. you **want to fetch the data  once** (e.g. by triggering the fetch from a button, or on page loading, etc..) you should only use the `once()` method and then you can chain the two calls as follows:

```
  var currency = 'EUR';
  var ref5 = db.ref().child('parentnode/currencies/value/' + currency + '_price');
  var ref6 = db.ref().child('parentnode/currencies/value/currency-source');

  ref5
    .once('value')
    .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      return ref6.once('value');
    })
    .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. the second approach is something feasible. but that means we will download all the data leaf under /currencies/value/  as

     var price = data[currency + '_price'] will work locally on the client. I thought there is a way to query specifically that key from firebase

Comment: Yes indeed. I actually thought about it after writing the answer yesterday :-) I've added to possible approaches in my answer.

Comment: @rayman **Actually note that in my initial answer I mixed-up the `once()` method with the `on()` one....** Since you want to set listeners you need to use the `on()` method (I've adapted the answer). If you just want to listen once (e.g. by triggering the fetch from a button, or on page loading, etc..) you should use the `once()` method.

Comment: @rayman Hi, did you have the opportunity to look at the update?

Comment: Yes,.in all your examples you download all leaf and you do local maniplution. I.wanted to.know if I could leverage firebase query to download only the currency-price the player need without downloading all.currencies.as we can get the hundred currencies easy. Thanks

Comment: @rayman Have a look at the updates I made on 1st December: "Set two listeners" and "Query the currency-source value within the listener". Only the necessary leaves are downloaded.